# Does Google people support "Extend an Android app to Google Assistant with App Actions" in Java?

Tags: java, android, actions-on-google, app-actions

There is an instruction and Kotlin sample code in the following site.

Extend an Android app to Google Assistant with App Actions:

[https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions/#0](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions/#0%C2%A0%C2%A0)

Is it possible to implement this function by Java not Kotlin?
I am wondering if Google people don't support the function in Java because it is the latest technology.
If they still support it in Java, can you share any Java sample code of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Not at the moment. There is tooling on the web to convert Java to Kotlin. But all current examples are based on Kotlin. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Maybe it is time to transfer to Kotlin for me in order to catch up with the up-to-date technologies.

Comment: Exactly. It's highly encouraged. You'll learn to love it once you pass some of the learning curve.